# using jQuery .live with .bind

Tags: jquery

okay, I understand the basics of jQuery, and I know that in some instances I've had to use `.live('click',function(){...});` instead of `.click(function(){...});` to get the method to fire correctly.

the method I'm currently looking at is:
`$('#title').bind('keyup', function(){...});`

This works great, except because it's in a bit of code that isn't called until another action is preformed, I'd need to use `.live()` as described above.

Problem is, I don't know how to format this one to work using the `.live()` method instead of `.bind()` as shown above. Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What bit of code is .live within? Can you give example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using live is the same as using bind, except that it is limited only to the events `click, dblclick, keydown, keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove, mouseout, mouseover, and mouseup.`

```
$('selector').live('event',fn);
```

Comment: okay, so if I use` $('#title').live('keyup', function(){...});` for my specific example... yes! it's worked! Thank you.

Comment: Sure thing, sorry for the hiccup.

Answer (score 0):

odd, I thought I saw the answer up, but then it seemed to disappear before I could accept. At any rate, using the following worked:

`$('#title').live('keyup', function(){...});`

Comment: The owner of that answer deleted it for some reason. Not sure why.

Comment: ...it was an accident :/ ... I don't remember confirming deletion.

Answer (score 0):

@dskvr is correct - the usage syntax is the same. But you also might like to read up on the [differences between live(), bind() and delegate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954932/difference-between-jquery-click-bind-live-delegate-trigger-functions-with-e).