# Get index of element as child relative to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have this markup:

```
<ul id="wizard">
    <li>Step 1</li>
    <li>Step 2</li>
</ul>
```

And I have this jQuery:

```
$("#wizard li").click(function () {
    // alert index of li relative to ul parent
});
```

How can I get the index of the child `li` relative to it's parent, when clicking that `li`?

For example, when you click "Step 1", an `alert` with "0" should pop up.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

```
$("#wizard li").click(function () {
    console.log( $(this).index() );
});
```

However rather than attaching one click handler for each list item it is better (performance wise) to use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) which would look like this:

```
$("#wizard").delegate('li', 'click', function () {
    console.log( $(this).index() );
});
```

In jQuery 1.7+, you should use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). The below example binds the event to the `#wizard` element, working like a delegate event:

```
$("#wizard").on("click", "li", function() {
    console.log( $(this).index() );
});
```

Comment: hi redsquare.. I'm practicing with jQuery, I'm kinda n00b about delegate :D .. why delegate is better than attaching events directly on the elements?

Comment: @steweb - Hey - because one event handler is much preferable to potentially many. Attaching events to the dom can be expensive if you have large lists so as a rule I try to use the above where possible rather than individual handlers on each element. One article that goes deeper is http://briancrescimanno.com/2008/05/19/an-introduction-to-javascript-event-delegation/ - also google 'javascript event delegation'

Comment: ok, so, managing events in this way it's something lighter than the classic 'dom attachment' :) ..thanks!

Comment: @steweb - It is also lighter because jquery doesnt need to do an initial lookup of all the li elements. It just looksup the container and listens at that level to see if the clicked object was an li.

Comment: This .index method is super helpful to me. I'm using jQuery Sortable to do sorting, but it stores the semantic ranking info in the DOM. With .index(), I can pull the ranking back out of the dom really cleanly. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer with the on() event handler with the same delegate principle usage.

Comment: @dan atkinson hey, small world, follow you on twitter....SO falls down with versioning a bit!

Comment: Noob question here: do that performance hint still makes sense today, or was that already abstracted out by the "compiler"? :P

Comment: Just found out it works differently with ES6 arrow function "() => {", the old one is more compatible, good to know

Answer (score 45):

something like:

```
$("ul#wizard li").click(function () {
  var index = $("ul#wizard li").index(this);
  alert("index is: " + index)
});
```

Comment: Great addition - we can find index relatively to the parent selector.
+1

Comment: prefer this answer as it actually answers the question rather then a possible solution for the example

Answer (score 11):

There's no need to require a big library like jQuery to accomplish this, if you don't want to. To achieve this with built-in DOM manipulation, get a collection of the `li` siblings in an array, and on click, check the `indexOf` the clicked element in that array.

```js
const lis = [...document.querySelectorAll('#wizard > li')];
lis.forEach((li) => {
  li.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const index = lis.indexOf(li);
    console.log(index);
  });
});
```

```html
<ul id="wizard">
    <li>Step 1</li>
    <li>Step 2</li>
</ul>
```

Or, with event delegation:

```js
const lis = [...document.querySelectorAll('#wizard li')];
document.querySelector('#wizard').addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  // Make sure the clicked element is a <li> which is a child of wizard:
  if (!target.matches('#wizard > li')) return;
  
  const index = lis.indexOf(target);
  console.log(index);
});
```

```html
<ul id="wizard">
    <li>Step 1</li>
    <li>Step 2</li>
</ul>
```

Or, if the child elements may change dynamically (like with a todo list), then you'll have to construct the array of `li`s on every click, rather than beforehand:

```js
const wizard = document.querySelector('#wizard');
wizard.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  // Make sure the clicked element is a <li>
  if (!target.matches('li')) return;
  
  const lis = [...wizard.children];
  const index = lis.indexOf(target);
  console.log(index);
});
```

```html
<ul id="wizard">
    <li>Step 1</li>
    <li>Step 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: $(...).indexOf is not a function

Comment: None of the code snippets on my answer produce that error - you can press "Run code snippet" to see them working. If you're getting that error, you're using different code - it sounds like you're using jQuery, but my answer is showing how to accomplish this sort of thing *without* jQuery

Comment: Fair enough. Yes, I am using JQuery. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KL3Vm/).

```
$("#wizard li").click(function () {
    alert($(this).index()); // alert index of li relative to ul parent
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Delegate and Live are easy to use but if you won't have any more li:s added dynamically you could use event delagation with normal bind/click as well. There should be some performance gain using this method since the DOM won't have to be monitored for new matching elements. Haven't got any actual numbers but it makes sense :)

```
$("#wizard").click(function (e) {
    var source = $(e.target);
    if(source.is("li")){
        // alert index of li relative to ul parent
        alert(source.index());
    }
});
```

You could test it at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jimmysv/4Sfdh/1/

Comment: To what are you referring to when you say this 'DOM won't have to be monitored'? jq delegate does not monitor the dom.

Comment: @redsquare I was under the impression that Delegate is just a more efficient variant of Live. This is from http://api.jquery.com/delegate/: "Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements." It must be monitoring to bind in the future?

Comment: nope it just uses delegation on the container like your code above. If you insert a new li element into the container the container click event is still fired and everything still works. No monitoring required.

Comment: @redsquare Yes, you are correct. My solution works even if there are new elements added after the DOM has loaded. Since Delegate uses Live internally (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954932/difference-between-jquery-click-bind-live-delegate-trigger-functions-with-e/2954951#2954951) it still feels like this is more optimized but less convenient. But as I said, I have no numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way

```
$("#wizard li").click(function () 
{
    $($(this),'#wizard"').index();
});
```

Demo
https://jsfiddle.net/m9xge3f5/