# getting index of an li in a ul?

Tags: jquery, traversal

I'm close to this but cross-brained on something.

I have this code:

```
var numOfLi = $('#myList li').length;
var lastLi = numOfLi;

$('.next').click(function() {
    var current = $('#myList').find('li.on');
    current.removeClass('on');
    current.next().addClass('on');
    var grabAlt = $('.on img').attr('alt').split('|');
    var holdAlt = grabAlt;
    $('#altStuff').html('<ul class="altDescription">' +
        '<li>' + holdAlt[0] + '</li>' + '<li>' + holdAlt[1] +
        '</li>' + '<li>' + holdAlt[2] + '</li>' + '</ul>');
});

$('.prev').click(function() {
    var current = $('#myList').find('li.on');
    current.removeClass('on');
    current.prev().addClass('on');
    var grabAlt = $('.on img').attr('alt').split('|');
    var holdAlt = grabAlt;
    $('#altStuff').html('<ul class="altDescription">' +
        '<li>' + holdAlt[0] + '</li>' + '<li>' + holdAlt[1] +
        '</li>' + '<li>' + holdAlt[2] + '</li>' + '</ul>');
});
```

It clicks forward and back through a list of Li's, assigns a class of 'on' to the li, grabs the alt text of the image in each Li, parses that and puts it into a paragraph.

This all works great and dynamically, but now I'm trying to stop the next/prev buttons when they reach the first/last li.

My thought is to: 1. upon clicking, check to see if the current li is the first one (don't let prev work) or the last one (don't let next work).

But, I'm a little mushed now as to how to check that. The .length only returns the count....so, how can I get the position value of whatever the current li is?

I was thinking I have to put all the li's of this ul into a matrix and then just check against it's index but I'm not getting that work.

Thanks for looking.

I was thinking I'd have to put the entire UL list into

Comment: Have you had a look at http://api.jquery.com/index/ ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Get index of element as child relative to parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996002/jquery-get-index-of-element-as-child-relative-to-parent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('li.on').index()
```

will give you the position of that `li` within it's parent.

Answer (score 0):

The [almost] absolute laziest, and not necessarily easiest, would be to keep track of which `li` you're on.

You already get the length, so you know that the last `li` would have an index of `numOfLi - 1`, and you know that the first `li` would have an index of 0.

So you could change it to something like this:

```
var numOfLi = $('#myList li').length;
var lastLi = numOfLi - 1;
var currentLi = 0; // I think? This wasn't clear.

$('.next').click(function () {
    if (currentLi !== lastLi) {
        currentLi += 1;
        // ...
    }
});

$('.prev').click(function () {
    if (currentLi) {
        currentLi -= 1;
        // ...
    }
});
```