# find index of child using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have an html structure like:

```
<div id="parent">
 <div class="child first">
   <div class="sub-child"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="child second">
   <div class="sub-child"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="child third">
   <div class="sub-child"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

and I have a click handler defined through `($('#parent.child')).click()` and then I click on the div with the class of `second` (`first, second, third` classes have simply been added to make demo clearer) is there a simple way to get the number 1 as it is the second child? (0 based index)?

Something like `$(this).index`

Comment: sorry I miss understood there.. i think you want to click on the second div and then somehow know that it is the second div in the event handling code?

Comment: check the first example on this page http://api.jquery.com/index/ ...hope it helps

Comment: `#parent .child` would be the right selector.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996002/jquery-get-index-of-element-as-child-relative-to-parent/4996037#4996037

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just have a look at the jQuery API. The method you suggest, [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/), is exactly right:

```
$('#parent .child').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
});
```

From the docs:

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is
>   an integer indicating the position of the first element within the
>   jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

Also note that I've changed the selector slightly from your example. I'm guessing that was just a typo in your question though. `#parent.child` will look for an element with ID "parent" and a class of "child", but you actually want `#parent .child` (note the space) to find elements with class "child" that are descendants of an element with ID "parent".

Comment: this guy suggest using delegate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4996037/359135 but basically has the same answer

Comment: @gordatron - Delegating the event higher up the DOM tree would likely be preferable, but I'm using `click` since that's what the OP has used in the question. Also, note that `delegate` has been replaced by `on` since jQuery 1.7.

Answer (score 9):

The [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method can be used for getting the position of an element inside a collection. In basic circumstances, `$(this).index()` should work.

But with more specific collections, you can get the position with `collection.index(item)`. Imagine adding something simple into your `#parent` that should not be counted when measuring `index()` (a `span`, `img`, anything). With the simple method, your code is likely to break, but with the specific method, it won't.

Something like this should work for you:

```
var $children = $('#parent .child').click(function​ () {
    console.log($children.index(this));
});​
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ET6YW/)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much. The approved answer didn't help me, but yours did the magic. And your explanation clarified why. Thanks a lot.