# jquery get current number of child

Tags: jquery, tags

```
<div id="sample">
  <h3>headline 1</h3>
  <h3>headline 2</h3>
  <h3>headline 3</h3>
</div>
```

How is it now possible to determine the clicked h3 child element and process this with jquery?

```
var id = $("h3").index();
```

this is'nt it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Get index of element as child relative to parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996002/jquery-get-index-of-element-as-child-relative-to-parent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside click handler, you have to refer to `$(this)` to refer to the clicked element. Try like

```js
$("h3").on("click",function(){


  alert($(this).index());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sample">
  <h3>headline 1</h3>
  <h3>headline 2</h3>
  <h3>headline 3</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the click event on h3 elements:

```
$("h3").click(function() {
  var index= $(this).index();
  alert(index);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6rm371mo/)**

Comment: this only returns 0 on no matter what child i click

Answer (score 1):

Pass `this` inside index function

```
$("h3").click(function(){
 var id = $("h3").index(this);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("h3").click(function(event){
  alert( $(this).index() + 1);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kk6sf2p9/)