# Getting the index of auto generated elements using class attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am following `aM1Ne` answer (the one with most vote)of this  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525664/jquery-how-to-bind-onclick-event-to-dynamically-added-html-element)  thread for binding event, as i am generating multiple element dynamically
My js code looks like

```
$(document).on('click', ".myCheckBox" , function() {
    //.....
});
```

Here `myCheckBox` is the class that is assigned to all generated check box. Now i want the index of the clicked checkbox. I have tried

```
alert($(this).index());
```

inside. But it always shows `0`. Is there any way to get the index of clicked check box which contains the `myCheckBox` class?

In HTML i Have a single check box

```
<input type="checkbox" name="" class="myCheckBox" >
```

and in a button and on its onclick

```
$("#clickAdd").click(function()
{
    ("#myDiv").append("<input type=\"checkbox\"  class=\"myCheckBox\" >");
 });
```

Comment: updated the question with html @Cerbrus

Comment: So, what "index" value do you want to get, then?

Comment: if i add more 3 check box using the `add` button and when clicked any of them i  want to know which check box was clicked. @Cerbrus

Comment: The clicked checkbox is just `this`.

Comment: Actually what i am looking for is like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996002/jquery-get-index-of-element-as-child-relative-to-parent thread explain we can get the li of a list which was clicked and the `index()` method also worked for tr. it it possible that i can get same type of result for multiple check box with same class.?  @Cerbrus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the real explanation, but this code worked like charm

```
$(document).on('click', ".myCheckBox" , function() {
     var checkIndex = $(this).closest('.myCheckBox').index('.myCheckBox');
     alert(checkIndex);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a slightly different approach, if you're able to assign the value while you're generating the checkboxes, eg:

```
$(cb).data('indexVal', index++);
```

You can assign arbitrary objects/information with [the data method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/).  You can then easily retrieve it within your click event handler:

```
alert($(this).data('indexVal'));
```

and it's read straight off the element without worrying where it is in the page.

Working with the HTML/script you've added, I would do this:

```
var indexVal = 1;
$("#clickAdd").click(function() {
    var inp = $('<input>', {type : 'checkbox' });
    inp.addClass('myCheckBox');
    inp.data('indexVal', indexVal++);
    ("#myDiv").append(inp);
});
```