# Get the number of nth child of a selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to figure out how to get the number of nth child of a selected element. For example if I have:

```
<parent>
  <child>a</child>
  <child>b</child>
  <child>c</child>
  <child>d</child>
  <child>e</child>
</parent>
```

Then if I have:

```
$('child').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).nthChildOf('parent'));
});
```

And I like the console to output `3` if I click on `c`.

Thanks for the speedy answer. I have an added question. I find that if I use:

```
<parent>
  <child onclick="nthOf(this)">a</child>
  <child onclick="nthOf(this)">b</child>
  <child onclick="nthOf(this)">c</child>
  <child onclick="nthOf(this)">d</child>
  <child onclick="nthOf(this)">e</child>
</parent>
```

and then:

```
function nthOf(e) {
  console.log($('parent').index(e));
}
```

It will always output 1.

And if I do:

```
function nthOf(e) {
  console.log($('parent').index($(e)));
}
```

It will always output -1.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I think you can find what you are looking for in this link [jQuery: Get index of element as child relative to parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996002/jquery-get-index-of-element-as-child-relative-to-parent)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rzq3r4tw/

Comment: @SunilKumar it seems to always output `-1`.

Comment: @JamesWayne : Did you try this ?

Comment: @SunilKumar here: http://jsfiddle.net/hm6ncfyL

Comment: Check this image: http://resizeimage.net/viewimg/VCEOrMmRCMm4pEub/DGy32/console.png

Comment: I gave this link : https://jsfiddle.net/rzq3r4tw/

Comment: @SunilKumar yes I forked it from the link and modified it so I can use `onclick` to activate it.

Comment: Here is a PURE JavaScript solution: https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/012s8g96/

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the number of element among its siblings.

```
$('child').click(function(){
  console.log($('child').index( this ) + 1);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/rrKVbE)**

In reply to your recent comment, I dunno what you are trying to achieve, but if thats what you want i'll give it to you :D so as per your update to the question. Your function should be ...

```
function nthOf(e) {
  console.log($(e).parent().children().index(e) + 1);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/pEKjEr)**

Comment: Bear in mind that if OP wants `3` when clicking on `c`, they'll need to add 1 to that. Also there's no need to pass in `this`.

Comment: Good catch there, James! I'll update the answer.

Comment: it is always return: 0

Comment: @shushil Updated code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rzq3r4tw/

Comment: Hey man I updated the question, can you take a look? Thanks.

Comment: @JamesWayne Why are you going for the inline js. When you can use event binding since you have `jQuery` included in your project. Just look at the demo that I linked to in my answer.

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib I have to use it because the click handler had been dedicated for another function.