# Multiple file upload using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to implement a multiple file upload where I am right now using a iframe post form and implementing some extra functionality in the call back function.

I now want to add multiple file upload so that new form fields are created on clicking submit on first one and the first one is removed and the next one starts uploading once that is complete. How can Iframepost form pick upload of next file on completion of one.

```
$('#id').iframepostform(function(){
post:blah blah
complete:
my functionality
}
```

now i want to make recursive calls to iframe post form with the id's changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been done many times before. I would recommend not writing another custom JavaScript file uploader (unless you *have* to for some other reason). I recommend the excellent [Pulpload](http://www.plupload.com/). I expect that it would be substantially less effort to use an existing, well-tested, proven solution over a new implementation.

**Edit:** That's unfortunate! However, I have [**built a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gEGse/2/) that I hope will help you reach a solution. It does not perform the jQuery AJAX [`post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) but it does clone a form, increment the field ID numbers and then remove the old form when the "upload" is complete. For the purposes of a demo I am simulating the "upload" with a simple [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout).

**Edit:** Full solution with [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

HTML:

```
<div>
    <form>
        <input type="file" id="form1_field1"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Make it so" id="form1_field2"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').live('click', function() {
    var formClone = $('form:first-child').clone();

    formClone.find('input').each(function(i) {
        $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id').replace(/form(\d+)/, function(fullMatch, n) { return 'form'+(Number(n)+1); }));
    });
    var thisForm = $(this).closest('form');
    $('div').append(formClone).children(':last').hide().fadeIn(1500);

    // do ajax post here (faking the "upload time" with a timeout)
    // but really the "hideFinishedForm" method body needs to
    // go in the upload success callback
    window.setTimeout(hideFinishedForm, 5000, thisForm);

    return false;
});

function hideFinishedForm(formToRemove) {
    $(formToRemove).remove();

    // now submit the next form
    $('form input[type="submit"]').trigger('click');
}
```

Further reading on the [Difference between jQuery `click`, `bind`, `live`, `delegate`, `trigger` and `on` functions (with an example)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954932/difference-between-jquery-click-bind-live-delegate-trigger-functions-with-e/2954951#2954951)

Comment: but the problem is i have an existing system out and need to extend that to allow multiple file uploads. So, is there a way i can add multiple file elements and update the iframepost form to loop through the hashed ids of the forms.

Comment: +1 this is an area where "roll your own" is the path to great pain

Comment: is there a way i can call a callback function recursively with some variable value from after iframepostform complete:

Comment: I've updated my answer with a demo which recursively submits a form. It's missing the AJAX post functionality but once you've clicked _submit_ it will fake an upload every 5 seconds. If you just want one iteration (so you can see what the code is doing) just comment out the line `$('form input[type="submit"]').trigger('click');`. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you....i got the gist of it, but as i am pretty new to JS, I will try this first...

Comment: Well I hope it helps. It might be easier for your implementation to allow users to add a new `<input type="file"/>` with a button (for example "Add another file" and then with one submit button just "submit" each individual form one by one with the _next_ upload triggered via the success callback from the _previous_ upload.

Comment: Ah ok, you can use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi andyb, I have a doubt if an upload like plupload is supported on IE 6 or old browsers??

Comment: Quite the opposite actually. It is designed to be completely backwards compatible and supports many different upload runtimes (Flash, Gears, HTML 5, Silverlight, BrowserPlus, HTML 4). Flash and Silverlight are both supported in IE6. I agree that there might not be _native_ support but there is certainly the capability for it to support old browsers.

Comment: So, if i use plupload and implement a form, what if flash is not used in a browser. does the upload fall back to a normal upload??

Comment: The [example page](http://www.plupload.com/example_all_runtimes.php) show all the different variations of the upload runtime. Without Flash, the HTML 4 runtime fallback still works in IE6.