# What's the difference between ".click(..." and ".bind('click..."(in plain English)?

Tags: jquery, events

I would like to know the difference between this:

```
$('#foo').click(function() {
  alert('User clicked on "foo."');
});
```

and this

```
$('#foo').bind('click', function() {
  alert('User clicked on "foo."');
});
```

(I read the documentation but I'm still not getting it).

Comment: Pls show me your documentations ?

Comment: similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954932/difference-between-jquery-click-bind-live-delegate-trigger-functions-with

Comment: One of them is a short-cut on saving a few characters :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$().click(fn)` and `$().bind('click', fn)` are identical at first sight, but the `$.bind` version is more powerful for 2 reasons:

- `$().bind()` allows you to assign one handler to multiple events, e.g. `$().bind('click keyup', fn)`.
- `$().bind()` supports [namespaced events](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events) - a powerful feature if you want to remove `$().unbind)` only certain event handlers that an element is bound to.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference but you can bind more than one event handler in one go using `bind`

`$('#foo').click(function(){})` when triggered will call

```
$('#foo').bind('click', function() {})
```

So

```
$('#foo').click(function() {
  alert('User clicked on "foo."');
});
```

and this

```
$('#foo').bind('click', function() {
  alert('User clicked on "foo."');
});
```

means same.

Another use of bind is:

```
$('#foo').bind('click mouseover focus', function() {
  alert('User clicked on "foo."');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The bind() method attaches one or more event handlers for selected elements, and specifies a function to run when the event occurs. The click() function does not bind multiple event handlers. The click() method triggers the click event, or attaches a function to run when a click event occurs.

```
$( "#button1" ).bind({
click: function() {
Do something on click
},
mouseenter: function() {
// Do something on mouseenter
}
});
```

and

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
alert('User clicked on button');
});
```