# jquery button not respond to click method

Tags: jquery, click

so i am dynamically rendering a paragraph with jquery using the append method and i want to add a click event to it but for some reason the click event is not working, i know the solution is probably simple but I am new to jquery and would appreciate any help...I know the code inside the function works because i tested it with a static button, it is just not working with the dynamic one..Thanks in advance for any help,

here is my code

```
$(this).parent().parent().children("div").append("<p class='tryAgain'>Try Again</p>");
```

the click function code,

```
$(".tryAgain").click(function() {......}
```

Comment: welcome to jquery. If you like more information on clicks, [click this link to similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954932/difference-between-jquery-click-bind-live-delegate-and-trigger-functions-wit). And please note that with latest jquery version (1.7), all event binding methods have been fused into one method to rule them all: `.on()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anything you add to the DOM after the document.ready has fired needs to use [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in order to add an event handler to the newly added element.

For instance:

```
$('.tryAgain').live("click", function() {...});
```

If you are using jquery 1.7+ you should use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on("click", ".tryAgain", function(){ ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [$.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) o [$.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$('.tryAgain').live('click', function()
{
  ....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to use live events, you can add the handler when you create the element like this:

```
$("<p>Try Again</p>", {
  "class": "tryAgain",
  click: function(){
     //YOUR CLICK HANDLER
  }
}).appendTo($(this).parent().parent().children("div"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can attach a click event right there when you create the new p tag like this:

```
$(this).parent().parent().children("div").append(
    $('<p>').addClass('tryAgain').click(function(){
        alert('test');
    }));
```