# Making Jeditable working on new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu, jeditable, filetree

I'm trying to make [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) works on new elements created using [this](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/) jquery file tree.

On right click on a folder or file a context menu is shown and after clicking "Rename" item on the context menu i want to activate Jeditable.

I'm using this context menu and [this](http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/index.html) code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#filetree').fileTree({
    root: '../../../',
    script: './connectors/jqueryFileTree.php',
    expandSpeed: 1000,
    collapseSpeed: 1000,
    multiFolder: true
}, function(file) {
    alert(file);
});

$.contextMenu({
    selector: 'ul.jqueryFileTree > li', 
    callback: function(key, options) {
        var m = "clicked: " + key;
        window.console && console.log(m);
        if(key == 'rename'){
            $('#1').trigger("edit1");
            }
    },
    items: {
        "rename": {name: "Rename", icon: "edit", accesskey: "r"},
        "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut", accesskey: "c"},
        // first unused character is taken (here: o)
        "copy": {name: "Copy", icon: "copy", accesskey: "c o p y"},
        // words are truncated to their first letter (here: p)
        "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste", accesskey: "cool paste"},
        "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
    }
});

/* Bind Jeditable instances to "edit" event. */


$("#1").editable("http://www.example.com/save.php", {
 event: 'edit1',

 });
});

});
```

But doesn't work, i've read on the web ([here](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_jeditable/issues/6))that i should use .live (.on() is ok? since i'm using jquery 1.7.1) but i don't know why, can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in place of [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) which works sort of like the [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method. live is bit expensive as it keep track of the DOM changes and for that it has to iterate where as the `.on()` or `.delegate()` simply delagate the event to a higher element like `document` or the `body`.

```
    $('.editableItem').live('click', function(){
        $(this).editable("http://www.example.com/save.php", {
     event: 'edit1',
     });
   });
```

**`Why you have to use live?`**

Because dynamically inserted elements into the DOM dont get attached to the event handlers automatically for that you have to use `live` or upon insertion of elements you can manually bind the elements to the event handlers by using [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

here are some useful questions

[Difference between jQuery `click`, `bind`, `live`, `delegate`, `trigger` and `on` functions (with an example)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954932/difference-between-jquery-click-bind-live-delegate-and-trigger-functions-wit)

[Jquery live() vs delegate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579117/jquery-live-vs-delegate)

http://paulirish.com/2010/on-jquery-live/

Comment: the problem is that when the item "Rename" is clicked it send a callback function and i don't know which dom element is it so i can't say when is clicked

Comment: It almost works with on(), but it requires you to click twice. The first click will initialize .editable and the second click will edit the field. How can this double click be avoided?