# Why is copy/paste entry into div using jeditable not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable

I'm using the jQuery jeditable to edit a div on a web form. Anything I type into this field regardless of length gets sent to the javascript function without error. But if I copy/paste something instead of typing then the data is not passed to the function, and the field blanks out.

The html looks like this;

```
<div id="forcb1" class="hidden">
    <div id="genComments" class="editGComms" onClick="getNetID();" > </div>
</div>
```

The function looks like this;

```
function getNetID(){
    var netid=$("#idofnet").html().trim(); 

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".editGComms").editable("SaveGenComm.php", {     
         indicator  : "Saving...",
         tooltip    : "Click to add...",
         style      : "inherit",
         id         : netid,
         name       : "newvalue"
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.
([Making Jeditable working on new elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285344/making-jeditable-working-on-new-elements))

Also same problem solved on: [How do I capture the input value on a paste event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902455/how-do-i-capture-the-input-value-on-a-paste-event)

```
<div id="forcb1" class="hidden">
    <div id="genComments" class="editGComms"></div>
</div>
---------------------------------------------------------------
document.getElementById("genComments").addEventListener("click", getNetID);

function getNetID(){
    //$(".editGComms").live('click', function(){
        var netid=$("#idofnet").html().trim();

        $(".editGComms").editable("SaveGenComm.php", {
            indicator  : "Saving...",
            tooltip    : "Click to add...",
            style      : "inherit",
            id         : netid,
            name       : "newvalue"
        });
    //});
}
```

Here is a new version of the function:

```
function getNetID(){
    $(".editGComms").live('click', function(){
        var netid=$("#idofnet").html().trim();

        $(".editGComms").editable("SaveGenComm.php", {
            indicator  : "Saving...",
            tooltip    : "Click to add...",
            style      : "inherit",
            id         : netid,
            name       : "newvalue"
        });
    });
}
```

I've also removed the "hidden" from the parent div in order to see the box (for now). But now I can't select the box (I can't put my cursor in the div) to type or paste into it.

Comment: I put your suggestion in place. But when I executed it I got; TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("genComments").addEventListener')

Comment: I see. You have class="hidden".  Try <div id="forcb1">  to see if it work for test......... if this dont work then uncomment the live.click {(....)} and comment out the addeventlistener part

Comment: I made the function look like the edit above. However I can't put my cursor in the box (div) in order to type. It doesn't go into edit mode.