# Jquery if else statement performance

Tags: jquery, performance, conditional-statements

I am designing a responsive layout with a carousel. The carousel has a control that allows the user to toggle the entire box, hiding and showing the carousel. You can see this fully working here: http://pixelcakecreative.com/cimlife/responsive2/

It seems like it is functioning very sluggishly. I was thinking that my jquery was written poorly, and it might be slowing the performance down. My jquery is as follows:

```
$("#closeBox a").click(function(){
            if ($(this).find('span').hasClass('minus')) {
               $(this).find('span').removeClass('minus').addClass('plus');
               $(".padCar").css("padding-bottom","0");

            } else if ($(this).find('span').hasClass('plus')) {
                 $(this).find('span').removeClass('plus').addClass('minus');
                 $(".padCar").css("padding-bottom","20px");
            }
            $('#carousel').slideToggle('slow');

        return false;
        });
```

Any ideas why it is so jumpy? Perhaps my jquery should be better written, or maybe it is something else on the page that causes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first off you need to cache your selectors, so you should use

```
var span = $(this).find('span');
```

And then just use `span.someFunction();` - this reduces DOM queries and will speed it up.

Also what about adding a context to your initial selector? So if you know the links you are targeting are within a div with a class of .myBox, use:

```
$('#closebox a', '.myBox')
```

Or even better, use delegate():

```
$('.myBox').delegate('#closebox a', 'click', function(){ ... });
```

**Update**

As John Hartsock and RightSaidFred pointed out, if using v1.7+, you should use on() rather than delegate(), as so:

```
$('.myBox').on('click', '#closebox a', function(){ ... });
```

Comment: If using jQuery 1.7 or higher on() and off() should be used instead of delegate.

Comment: Tom, Im not sure I understand the latter part of your answer. Why would I use this delegate/on method?

Comment: Very true, requiring the simple change of 'delegate' to 'on' in the above code.

Comment: @JCHASE11 The final part is a better way of binding event listeners to elements, say for instance if at some point you have a dynamically created '#closebox a' element, the click() binding won't apply to it. Here's an article on the subject: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-the-difference-between-live-and-delegate/

Comment: @TomWalters: Well, you'd need to swap the first two arguments (to use `.on()` that is).

Comment: Yes, but because there will be no dynamically added items to the carousel, what is the purpose of using delegate? If it will remain static, would there be any performance increase?

Comment: There is some gain, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954932/difference-between-jquery-click-bind-live-delegate-and-trigger-functions-wit

Comment: I tried it, and although it works, I dont notice any performance increases

Comment: Well I suspect there are other factors, the page you link to is loading scripts in the head, why not move them to the footer?

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of redundancy there, you can start replacing these `$(this).find('span')` to `var span = $(this).find('span')`

```
$("#closeBox a").click(function(){
       var span = $( this ).find( 'span' );
       if ( span.hasClass('minus')) {
           span.removeClass('minus').addClass('plus');
           $(".padCar").css("padding-bottom","0");
       } else if ( span.hasClass('plus')) {
          span.removeClass('plus').addClass('minus');
          $(".padCar").css("padding-bottom","20px");
       }
       $('#carousel').slideToggle('slow');
       return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#closeBox a").click(function(){
var spn = $(this).find('span');
            if (spn.hasClass('minus')) {
               spn.removeClass('minus').addClass('plus');
               $(".padCar").css("padding-bottom","0");

            } else {
                 spn.removeClass('plus').addClass('minus');
                 $(".padCar").css("padding-bottom","20px");
            }
            $('#carousel').slideToggle('slow');

        return false;
        });
```