# Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: value is not defined;
Bindings value: text: value.

Here's my code

```
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(myObject.storeRows),document.getElementById("addNewUpdateForm"));
           $("#abc").live('click',function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "request.json",
        //GET method is used
        type: "post",
        //pass the data
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(response) {
            function viewModelSku()  {
                self = this;
                this.skuData = skuData;
            }
            var skuData = response.Rows;
            ko.applyBindings(viewModelSku(), document.getElementById("Row"));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: dont use live(), use on(). before it read the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954932/difference-between-jquery-click-bind-live-delegate-trigger-and-on

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your view. You are binding to `value` whereas apparently this property does not exist in viewModelSku. Perhaps you want to bind to `skuData.value` inside your view (if that is property on skuData)