# Comparing efficency of jQuery selectors, which one is mor efficient

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Which of the following ways is more efficient? What is the difference?

A

```
  $("body").on('click', '.picker', function(){ alert("A");});
```

B

```
  $('.picker').on('click', function(){ alert("B");});
```

Comment: Have you tried profiling this, either in your browser's dev tools or on a site like jsperf?

Comment: They're not comparable, so their 'efficiency' is irrelevant.

Comment: You're comparing the selectors (DOM selection)? Or the efficiency of the event handling? I can't tell what you're asking. Like @DavidThomas suggested, your two lines of code are doing two different things.

Comment: As to the difference: [Difference between jQuery `click`, `bind`, `live`, `delegate`, `trigger` and `on` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954932/difference-between-jquery-click-bind-live-delegate-trigger-and-on)

Comment: If there are many `.picker` elements or if they're created dynamically it would make sense to use B, otherwise I'd use A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the situation.

`A` advantages

- `.picker` could be more than just a few. Delegating the handler to a parent, and not attaching a handler to each `.picker` reduces overhead.
- If `.picker` is an element that is loaded dynamically, but you need to set handlers ahead of time.

`B` advantages

- The handler is directly on the element. The event does not need to bubble up the DOM to trigger handlers.

In a similar context, `.live` was deprecated because handlers were placed on `document`, the highest node in the DOM tree. It caused latency.